# Why does the query optimizer use sort after merge join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Consider this query:

```
select
    map,line,pda,item,qty,qty_gift,pricelist,price,linevalue,vat,
    vat_value,disc_perc,disc_value,dt_disc_value,netvalue,imp_qty,
    imp_value,exp_qty,exp_value,price1,price2,price3,price4,
    justification,notes
  from appnameV2_Developer.dbo.pt
  where exists (select 1 from [dbo].[dt] dt 
                where pt.map=dt.map and dt.pda=pt.pda and dt.canceled=0)
except
select 
    map,line,pda,item,qty,qty_gift,pricelist,price,linevalue,vat,
    vat_value,disc_perc,disc_value,dt_disc_value,netvalue,imp_qty,
    imp_value,exp_qty,exp_value,price1,price2,price3,price4,
    justification,notes
  from appnameV2_Developer_reporting.dbo.pt
```

I made this to make sure there is no data difference in the same table (pt) between a replication publisher database(appnameV2_Developer) and its subscriber database(appnameV2_Developer_reporting). The specific replication article has a semijoin on dt.

dt is a transaction header table with PK (map,pda)

pt is a transaction detail table with PK (map,pda,line)

[Here's the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyahFTncX)

So, we have a Right Semi Join merge join. I would expect its result to be ordered by (map,pda,line). But then, a sort operator on (map,pda,line) is called.

Why does this sort occur (or, more accurately: why is the data not already sorted by that point)? Is the query optimizer lacking the logic of "when merge joining then its output is (still) sorted on the join predicates"?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, data is originally sorted by map, line, pda and the sort operation orders by map, pda, line I think. Interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Because it decided to use a "Merge Join" to execute the `EXCEPT` clause. In order to perform a Merge Join both datasets must have the same ordering.

The thing is, the inner Merge Join (before the EXCEPT) is based on the table `dt`, not on `pt`. Therefore, the resulting rows won't have the same ordering as the other side of the `EXCEPT`, that is based on `pt`.

Why does SQL Server do that? Not clear. I would have done it differently. Maybe the stats are not updated. Maybe there is small amount of rows where the strategy does not matter too much.

Comment: They're asking about a sort that occurs *between* two merges, where one of the inputs to the first merge is also the other input to the second merge. Given that a merge requires sorted inputs and should emit rows in that same order, they're asking why the intermediate sort operation is required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because they do not share the same ordering. One is based on `dt`, the second is based on `pt`.

Comment: Merge requires *both* inputs to be sorted in the same order. Both merges are using `pt`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever "Both merges are using pt" -- not true. Look at the execution plan. Contrary to what I expected (and you too) SQL Server does it upside down. Do you see the "Right Semi Join" there? I was expecting a "Left Semi Join".

Comment: I am looking at the execution plan. We must be talking at cross purposes somehow but I'm not sure how. The plan includes 3 clustered index scans which are fed directly into merge. Two of those scans are against the same table. And merge requires both inputs to be sorted the same way. Therefore, in the absence of *those* inputs being sorted, we can anyway conclude that `dt` and `pt` have the same ordering.

Comment: "dt and pt have the same ordering" -- well... almost. `pt` has the extra column `line` in the clustered index. Probably that's why the optimizer enforces a sort to make sure the first dataset is fully sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The results from the first merge will be sorted by `map, pda, line`. However, you yourself mentioned join predicates, and the join predicates for this first merge are only based on `map, pda` (they're the predicates from inside the `exists` clause, except the `cancelled` one has been pushed down to the index scan). All that that first merge *required* was input sorted by `map` and `pda`, and so that's the only sort order guaranteed on that data, so far as the rest of the query is concerned.

But as we know, the outputs from this first merge were actually derived from input that was additionally sorted by `line`. It appears the optimizer isn't currently able to spot this circumstance. It may be that the order of optimizations mean that it's unlikely ever to recognise this situation. So currently, it introduces the extra sort.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to tell with your 1-note. Do you want me to paste the plan somewhere else? Or maybe reply to a series of questions? No problem for me.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - I'm saying that I can't actually see what predicates are being applied at each node on pastetheplan, whereas with an actual plan in SSMS, I can see that information when I hover over them - but I'm not sure if that's a problem with me or with the tool. So it was more "I strongly believe what I'm saying is true here but lack the means to verify it myself".

Comment: I'm not an expert of reading plans, but shouldn't the xml part of pastetheplan contain all info that you could view in a more useful environment?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd not noticed the XML tab before :-)